# Math book with problems and solutions

Tags: books, exercises, probsoln

I am making a book of problems and solutions. Each chapter has several problems and I would like to include a separate chapter for the solution of each problem in each chapter. More or less, the draft of my book looks like the following.
[image: Chapter 1]

[image: Chapter 2]

[image: Chapter 3]

I only know how to make basic articles in latex but I never had experience in writing a book. So I need help how to make this? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: My willowtreebook class (on CTAN) has support for writing books of mathematics, including having problems appear in the text, with solutions in the back: https://ctan.org/pkg/willowtreebook

Answer (score 1):

In the `book` document class, you have five 'levels' of heading: parts, chapters, sections, subsections and subsubsections. You could have the different problems as sections under their relevant chapters, and then in the solutions chapter, have each previous chapter as a subsection and the individual problems as subsubsections. I would recommend cross-referencing the answers to the problems using the `\ref` command as well.

Comment: I believe there are `part`s an `paragraph`s in the heading’s levels of book class

Comment: @LuisTurcio I didn't know about parts, but I didn't include paragraphs because they do not show up in the contents page.

Comment: @DJScythe21 - The reason `paragraph`- and `subparagraph`-level headers don't feature in the ToC by default is purely because the `book` class sets `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` along with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}`. If one wants  paragraph-level headers to be numbered in the document *and* show up in the ToC, all one has to do is run `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` in the preamble.

Comment: You seem to be skipping sections in the solutions chapter.  This seems more logical: chapter = solutions; section = original chapter; subsection = original problem.  However, part was added as an edit, so maybe split the book into two parts: problems and solutions.  Then the chapter/problem structure could remain parallel.

Answer (score 1):

My [willowtreebook](https://ctan.org/pkg/willowtreebook) class (on CTAN, a derivative of the sophisticated memoir class) has support for writing books of mathematics, including having problems appear in the text, with solutions in the back: